# Replacing WiX variables from within Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, wix

I'm working to localise the installer that I've made in the WiX toolset and I'm trying to make my License Agreement change depending on the msi that's generated. If the msi is from the en-us folder in debug then it should be English, or French if it's in the fr-fr folder.
I currently have the two license files for English and French respectively:

- License.rtf
- LicenseFR.rtf

In my file Product.wxs I have the line

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="License.rtf"/>
```

My understanding is that the variable with Id 'WixUILicenseRtf' can be replaced when linking using the command line:

```
light -ext WixUIExtension -cultures:fr-FR -dWixUILicenseRtf=LicenseFR.rtf Product.wixobj -out Product.msi
```

So that this way this msi will display the French License Agreement.

However, how could this be set up from within visual studio such that it generates these whenever I click "rebuild" on the solution?

Comment: Wix project knows about "cultures", using .wxl files, and it can build as many setups as there are .wxl files. Names of these files must follow a naming convention.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627633/is-it-possible-to-localize-eula-in-wix-using-wxl-file