# Having trouble replacing WixVariable value

Tags: c#, wix

I'm trying to replace the value of WixUILicenseRtf in the file Product.wxs here

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="License.rtf"/>
```

I've used the command

```
candle.exe Product.wxs
```

and when I use

```
light.exe Product.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension -cultures:fr-fr -dWixUILicenseRtf=newlicense.rtf -loc Product_fr-FR.wxl -out French.msi
```

It claims that "The term -dWixUILicenseRtf=newlicense is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

What am I doing wrong here?
Edit: I would like to point out that I made a similar question earlier. This concerns the syntax for doing things over command line, while the other one concerns automating the process through Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing WiX variables from within Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68455366/replacing-wix-variables-from-within-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: you just created two identical questions? maybe will be better to edit one of them? creating duplicates will not help your question to get more answers.

Comment: They're not identical. One question is about automating it through Visual Studio, this is about doing it through command line.